# Ubuntu/Debian: Show list of available versions of a specific package

Tags: ubuntu, packages

How can I list all available versions of specific package?

I know with

```
apt-get install myPackage=1.2.3
```

a specific version could be installed.
And with

```
apt-show-versions -a myPackage
```

I would get a list of versions that are known by the system.

But how getting a list of all available versions. 
I think that isn't possible using the apt tools because they are
restricted to configured repositories.

So what is the way to go? Some web-repositories? What is the recommondation for Ubuntu 8.04?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try with

> apt-cache madison myPackage

Quote from man page:

> It displays available versions of a package in a tabular format.

Comment: [The madison tool no longer exists](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-there-an-apt-cache-command-madison). Now we have `apt-cache showpkg` and `apt-cache policy`.

Comment: This seems to only show locally available versions of the package. If you want all versions (including remote), this might do it: https://askubuntu.com/a/449/48214

Answer (score 9):

```
apt-cache policy myPackage
```

Answer (score 9):

If you like to know which package versions are included into some
particular Debian/Ubuntu/Backports release, **rmadison** tool from
**devscripts** package could be the answer. For example:

```
$ rmadison -u debian,ubuntu,bpo mercurial | cut -d "|" -f 1-3
debian:
 mercurial | 0.9.1-1+etch1 |     etch-m68k 
 mercurial | 0.9.1-1+etch1 |     oldstable 
 mercurial |  1.0.1-5.1 |        stable 
 mercurial |    1.5.1-2 |       testing 
 mercurial |    1.5.2-1 |      unstable 
ubuntu:
 mercurial |      0.7-8 | dapper/universe 
 mercurial |    0.9.5-3 | hardy/universe 
 mercurial | 1.0.1-5.1~hardy1 | hardy-backports/universe 
 mercurial | 1.1.2-2ubuntu1 | jaunty/universe 
 mercurial |    1.3.1-1 | karmic/universe 
 mercurial |    1.4.3-1 | lucid/universe 
 mercurial |    1.5.2-1 | maverick/universe 
bpo:
 mercurial | 1.0.1-5.1~bpo40+1 | etch-backports 
 mercurial | 1.3.1-1~bpo50+2 | lenny-backports
```

It will show "official" information, regardless of repositories you
have configured on your system.

Please note, that versions between releases are not kept as a part of
official repositories. However, you can give a shot to recently
launched http://snapshot.debian.org service, which allows to access to
old packages based on dates and version numbers uploaded to Debian
archive since around 2005.

Similar tool you may be interested in is **whohas**, which goes far
beyond Debian family. It's able to show versions of available software
for other distributions (Arch, openSUSE, Gentoo, FreeBSD and even more
- 14 distros at the moment).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

As @Ilya pointed out you can use `whohas`:

```
whohas -d Debian,Ubuntu package | tr -s ' ' '\t' | cut -f 1-3 | column -t
```

Comment: Still needs an extra package, and much more typing, so why would we want this option?